# Why the return does not print the inner functions results?

Tags: python

I have tested with both jupyter and python terminal, that when the codes reach return, it outputs the result, even if it true or false, but why it does not print the inner function results? Does python always print the return result?

```py
def is_evern(i):
  if i%2==0: 
    print(i,'is even')
    return(True)
  print(i,'is odd')
  return(False)



def func_call(i):
  return(True)
```

Output of the commands:

```py
>>> is_evern(5)
5 is odd
False
>>> func_call(is_evern(5))
5 is odd
True
>>>
```

Comment: The question is quite confusing, what is the issue here? You have a print statement inside your function, so it is outputting the results of the inner function correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has three types of scopes:
1. Built-in
2. Global
3. Enclosed
4. Local

When you use the terminal, you are in Global scope, and it only has access to the first functions that you are calling. When you type the name of the function and call it, the terminal(python command line), is only seeing the immediate return, and it prints it, but has no access to the inner return, so you need to pass it to higher scope to be visible for the python.

Answer (score 1):

When running commands interactively, Python prints the result of the expression you type. Additionally, it will print anything you output with `print` statements.

However, it does not print the result of *every* function you call. Just the last one.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a function with a return statement, but you don't assign that return to an actual variable, it will print the returned value

```
x = func_call(is_evern(5))
>>5 is odd
```

returning to a variable will prevent the return from printing. Or just don't return a variable if you have no intention of using it

Answer (score 0):

It didn't print the results because you didn't tell it to do so.  `return` and `print` are very different commands.

Perhaps you're confused because of the expression evaluation inherent in many IDEs (interactive development environment).  Python's interactive mode is one of these: if given an *expression*, rather than a *command*, the interpreter will print the expression's value; this is a feature of the IDE.

For instance, if you enter `2+3`, the IDE will display `5`.  If you enter `a = 2+3`, the IDE will print nothing (but `5` gets assigned to `a`).

Now, let's walk through your IDE display:

```
>>> is_evern(5)
5 is odd              this comes from your print command
False                 this is the result of the expression "is_evern(5)"
>>> func_call(is_evern(5))
5 is odd              this comes from your print command
True                  this is the result of the expression
```

In this second statement, you don't get `False` because that's not the result of the whole expression.  Instead, that value got assigned to `i` in `func_call`, used immediately.

Answer (score 0):

"what happens" going step by step:

`iseven(5)`
5 is passed to function
in function:
evaluated `i%2` which is 5%2 => 1
evaluated `1==0` => `False` (skipps `if` block)
`print(i, 'is odd')` outputs `5 is odd`
returning `False` (btw, return doesn't need parentheses, only whitespace: `return False`)
`False` is now sort of in the place of `iseven(5)`
so `>>> iseven(5)` is equal to writing `>>> False`
pythons IDLE (and other IDEs) are built so that if after `>>>` there is something other than `None` (builtin object), it is printed out

check by typing

```
>>> False
False # expected output
>>> None
>>> # no output
```

**main problem**
`func_call(is_evern(5))`
`iseven(5)` is evaluated like in 1st paragraph and False is returned (note: evaluation requires printing `5 is odd`)
and again `False` is in place of `iseven(5)`
so: `func_call(is_evern(5))` equals to `func_call(False)`
now `False` is passed to `func_call`
inside of function:
`i` has value `False`
`True` is returned
`>>> True` is in place of `>>> func_call(is_evern(5))`
and, for reasons explained in last row 1st paragraph, True is printed